# Color palette of seaborn scatterplot is not working

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot, color-palette

I am trying to use the sequential color brewer palette of seaborn scatter plot, but it does not work properly. This is what I have done so far. I would appreciate any help.

```py
import seaborn as sns
from random import randrange

y = [randrange(100) for i in range(50)]
x = [i for i in range(50)]
ax = sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=y, s=15, c=y, palette=sns.color_palette("YlOrBr", as_cmap=True))
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`palette` is tied to `hue`, so change `c` to `hue`:

```py
ax = sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=y, s=15, hue=y, palette="YlOrBr", legend=False)
```

[image]